# Coloring middle of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, colors, pre

I have this as a string in a javascript document (taken from a pre tag in my HTML):

```
sqlString = "UPDATE galleria SET image_description = @image_description WHERE id = " + image.Id + " AND image_id = " + @image_id;
```

and I wish to color the text that is written within the quotation marks ("). I know I can do this with putting

```
<span style="color:red;">*text here*</span>
```

but I'm not sure how to do it. So far I've made an algorithm that gets the positions in the string of the quotation marks (for example in this string, I have 2 variables with the values 12 and 83), but to manipulate the string and post it back so that the above string becomes

```
sqlString = <span style="color:red;">"UPDATE galleria SET image_description = @image_description WHERE id = "</span> + image.Id + <span style="color:red;">" AND image_id = "</span> + @image_id;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `substring` and concatenation. Assuming `indexOfStartQuote` and `indexOfEndingQuote`, then:

```
sqlString = sqlString.substring(0, indexOfStartQuote) +
            '<span style="color: red">' +
            sqlString.substring(indexOfStartQuote + 1, indexOfEndingQuote + 1) +
            '</span>' +
            sqlString.substring(indexOfEndingQuote + 2);
```

...and then use that to set `innerHTML` on the element.

You may want to play with the `+ 1`s in there, depending on whether you want the quotes to be in red.

---

Side note: I'd advocate using `<span class="error">` or some such instead, and doing the styling with a `style` element or a stylesheet.

Comment: Absolutely magnificent. I am actually using the class of the span, I just wanted it to come across as easy-reading. But thank you very much! This worked perfectly.

Comment: @LarsJensen: LOL! That's funny. Glad that helped.